# I don't understand the equivalence between these two logic formulae

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm having trouble understanding the correction of an exercise. Could someone please explain how the second formula was deduced from the first one ?

$\exists u \exists v \forall x \neg (\neg v = c \rightarrow u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) = c) $

$\exists u \exists v \forall x \neg (\neg v = c \wedge u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) \neq c) $

c is a constant, $\circledcirc$ and $\circledast$ are binary functions.

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Are you sure that second one isn't supposed to be $\exists u\exists v\forall x(\neg v = c \wedge u \cdot(v * x)\ne c)$?

Comment: I copied exactly what was in the correction given by the teacher.
The binary functions are arbitrary, they don't have a specified definition.

Comment: Well you should check it again, as $(\neg v = c \wedge u \cdot(v * x)\ne c)$ and $(\neg v = c \rightarrow u \cdot(v*x) = c)$ are negations of each other.

Comment: I checked again the paper clearly says :
the original formula is : $\forall u \forall v \exists x (\neg v = c \rightarrow u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) = c) $
it's negation is $\exists u \exists v \forall x \neg (\neg v = c \rightarrow u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) = c) $ ans it's equivalent to $\exists u \exists v \forall x \neg (\neg v = c \wedge u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) \neq c) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we have the following equivalence:

**Implication**

$\neg (\phi \rightarrow \psi) \Leftrightarrow (\phi \land \neg \psi)$

Applied to your formula:

$\neg (\neg v = c \rightarrow u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) = c) \Leftrightarrow (\neg v = c \land  u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) \not = c)$

If these formulas are part of a larger formula, the equivalence remains. Thus we also have:

$\exists u \exists v \forall x \neg (\neg v = c \rightarrow u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) = c) \Leftrightarrow
\exists u \exists v \forall x (\neg v = c \land u \circledcirc  (v \circledast x) \not = c) $

So ... you have an extra $\neg$ in the second formula given to you ... the professor must have forgotten to remove it.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot ! I was having trouble understanding it but it seems it's because of that extra negation mark. (We've got a pdf file so no mistakes writing it down).